# Compute Taylor series $\frac{1}{x^2+4x+3}$ at $x = 2$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I was trying to solve a textbook exercise stated in the following:

Use completing the square and the geometric series to get the Taylor expansion about $x=2$ of $
\frac{1}{x^2+4x+3}$

My early attempt was

$\frac{1}{x^2+4x+3} = -1 (\frac{1}{1-(x+2)^2})$, even though the expression inside the parenthesis is of the form of geometric series $\frac{1}{1 - x}$. I realized that $x=2$ is not in the convergence domain of geometric series i.e. $|(x+2)^2| < 1$. So I should be wrong to proceed in this direction.

Could you please provide me some other directions to work with?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^2+4x+3}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+3}\right)$.

Comment: If you need to use completing the square and geometric series, the problem statement must be wrong.  It should probably be $x^2-4x+3$ in the denominator.

Comment: This problem appears on the wiki page for the Coursera Penn Single Variable Calculus course (although the asker may have gotten this problem elsewhere). Within the course, this is a similar problem about finding the Taylor expansion of $\frac{-1}{x^2+4x+3}$ about x=-2. Based on this, it seems likely that the problem statement is incorrect: either the expansion point here should also be x=-2 or the denominator was written incorrectly as mentioned by J Heller.

Answer (score 3):

Using partial fraction decomposition we get that

$$\frac{1}{x^2+4x+3} = \frac{1}{(x+3)(x+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+3}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-2}{3}} - \frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x-2}{5}} \right)$$

where we can now use geometric series to get

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{5^{n+1}}\right)(-1)^n(x-2)^n$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is applying partial fraction decomposition a special case here, or applying partial fraction decomposition is a common technique for taylor expansion?